# Lazy Initialization Errors from Refreshes

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

How can I prevent LazyInitializationExceptions from being thrown when a page is requested multiple times?  If I simply hold Ctrl-R on a page in my webapp, I consistently receive this message in my log files.

I have the following interceptor configured in my servlet.xml file:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean 
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor" />  
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Yet I constantly receive the following errors:

```
2011-09-23 15:14:28,854 [http-8080-23] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/web-app].[springmvc]  - Servlet.service() for servlet springmvc threw exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: illegal access to loading collection
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:366)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:186)
```

Note: Turning logging on the Interceptor I clearly see that it's being invoked and opening / closing transactions:

```
2011-09-23 15:36:53,229 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor IP134.167.141.34 CV#ef955014-cc9d-42fc P#75004 - Opening single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewInterceptor
2011-09-23 15:36:53,229 [http-8080-5] WARN  eqip.core.springmvc.extensions.interceptors.AbstractAgencyDataInterceptor IP134.167.141.34 CV#ef955014-cc9d-42fc P#75004 - Pre handle: http://134.167.141.34:8080/web-app/main.xhtml Status: 200
```

2011-09-23 15:36:53,511 [http-8080-5] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog IP134.167.141.34 CV#ef955014-cc9d-42fc P#75004 - Narrowing proxy to class core.model.entities.Subclass - this operation breaks ==
2011-09-23 15:36:53,511 [http-8080-5] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog IP134.167.141.34 CV#ef955014-cc9d-42fc P#75004 - Narrowing proxy to class core.model.entities.Subclass - this operation breaks ==
2011-09-23 15:36:53,916 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor IP134.167.141.34 CV#ef955014-cc9d-42fc P#75004 - Flushing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewInterceptor
2011-09-23 15:36:53,916 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet IP134.167.141.34 CV#ef955014-cc9d-42fc P#75004 - Rendering view [eqip.core.springmvc.extensions.velocity.VelocityToolsLayoutView: name 'pages/myEqip'; URL [pages/main.xhtml]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc'
2011-09-23 15:36:54,213 [http-8080-5] DEBUG eqip.core.springmvc.extensions.velocity.VelocityToolsLayoutView IP134.167.141.34 CV#ef955014-cc9d-42fc P#75004 - Rendering screen content template [pages/main.xhtml]
2011-09-23 15:36:54,384 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor IP134.167.141.34 CV#ef955014-cc9d-42fc P#75004 - Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewInterceptor

Using Spring 3.0.5, Hibernate 3.6.5, velocity 1.7

**Final Fix**: Was adding the following to our controller declarations:

```
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```

This allowed us to keep use of our interceptors and ensure that we were getting new copies of our pre-loaded pieces on each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you are saving some hibernate objects in the session, these objects might have uninitialized proxies.

Each time you press Ctrl+R, new request opens, and it is not possible to initialize proxy object from previous request durring the current request and as the result `LazyInitializationException` exception raises.

If this is not your case, then try to dig  it in this direction.

Comment: Which session?  The Http Session or the Hibernate session?  How would I verify?

Comment: Http session, somehow your unitialized proxies are forwarded to next request. I just recommend you to look in to your application logic or just debug it.

Comment: Ill double check on that. Perhaps something is sticking on redirect.

Comment: This put me on the right track.  The real issue for me was in the use of an interceptor which was loading data for me prior to the request being processed and setting these field values for use in the Controller code.  I was thinking that Spring instantiated a new Object for each request, however these values are cached by Spring.  Thus these fields were being overwritten by subsequent requests causing my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that interceptor class is actually called? Get the sources, and do a debug on it to see if the execution actually gets to it. Make sure you've actually declared that interceptor as an interceptor in your spring mvc configuration:

```
 <bean id="urlMapping"class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping"> 
<property name="interceptors">
<list>
<ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptor"/>
</list>
</property>

<property name="mappings">

</bean>
```

Or you can just go with the simpler OpenSessionInVIewFilter, which only needs to be configured as a servlet filter that intercepts /* (or a generic enoug URL to encompass all the urls of your controllers that deal with hibernate entities).

Comment: We received the same problem with the OSIVF as well.

Comment: Believe me, I feel for you. That's one of the "blessings" of using Hibernate which is crappy as is, wrapped in another heavyweight framework such as Spring, you kindda get lost in the thing. My choice for avoiding LAzyInitialisation... is to fetch all the needed data for the current view right from the start, using "fetch join"s. I mean why do you need to have Hibernate issue a bunch of selects when one is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Write a Class like :-

```
public class CustomHibernateSessionViewFilter extends   OpenSessionInViewFilter {

protected Session getSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory) throws DataAccessResourceFailureException {
    Session session = super.getSession(sessionFactory);
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
    return session;
}

protected void closeSession(Session session, SessionFactory factory) {
    session.flush();
    super.closeSession(session, factory);
}
```

}

Declare it in web.xml like this:-

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OSIVF Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>your.path.to.CustomHibernateSessionViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OSIVF Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```